# Сериализация в JSON Uwp

Tags: c#, json, uwp, serialize

Пытаюсь сериализовать проект, но все время получаю исключение при считывании строки

```
 [DataContract]
public class ImageManipulatorViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
  [DataMember]
public ObservableCollection<Collage> ImageList
{
    get { return this.imageList; }
    set
    {
        this.imageList = value;
        base.RaisePropertyChanged("ImageList");
    }
}
var storageFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
var sampleFile = await storageFolder.CreateFileAsync("MyProject.Collage", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
string l =JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this.ImageList);
аwait FileIO.WriteTextAsync(sampleFile, l);
string tres = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(l).ToString();
this.ImageList.Clear();
this.ImageList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<Collage>>(tres.ToString());
}


public class Collage
{
public Thickness Position { get; set; }
public WriteableBitmap Image { get; set; }
}
```

Получаю такую ошибку

```
Сould not create an instance of type Windows.Storage.Streams.IBuffer. Type is an interface or abstract class and cannot be instantiated. Path '[0].Image.PixelBuffer', line 10, position 23.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых `WriteableBitmap` не сериализуется, поэтому был заменен на `URI`
Во-вторых `ObservableCollection<Т>` необходимо преобразовать в `List<T>`

Код будет следующий

```
 var file = await savePicker.PickSaveFileAsync();
 var ser = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this.ImageList.ToList());
 await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(file, ser);
```